# displaying point cloud in rviz from .bag files, error

Tags: rviz, rosbag, transform, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to read .bag files, display the point cloud data in rviz.

```
rosbag play -l refined_point_clouds.bag 
[ INFO] [1313454488.757094980]: Opening refined_point_clouds.bag

Waiting 0.2 seconds after advertising topics... done.

Hit space to toggle paused, or 's' to step.
 [RUNNING]  Bag Time: 1284056763.769318   Duration: 1.105802 / 4.917923
```

But I got the following error,
[image: image description]

saying that

> For frame
> [narrow_stereo_optical_frame]: No
> transform to fixed frame [/base_link].
> TF error: [You requested a transform
> that is -1284043982668.005 miliseconds
> in the past, but the most recent
> transform in the tf buffer is
> -1284043980431.589 miliseconds old. ]

The coordinate frame in rviz was set as

[image: image description]

The point cloud would appear correctly if i changed the fixed frame to /narrow_stereo_optical_frame.

The error seems related with the tf conversion time longer than the buffer can take.Confused... Could someone explain it to me? How can I avoid this problem, 'cuz I always stuck in this kind of problem... Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10906/displaying-point-cloud-in-rviz-from-.bag-files,-error/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the tf exists between the /base_link frame and /narrow_stereo_optical_frame?

You can verify this by adding "tf" in the rviz display, and checking the tf tree.

They should appear cascaded

/base_link (parent)

/narrow_stereo_optical_frame (child)

If it does exists try adding playing the rosbag with the clock command:

rosbag play -l refined_point_clouds.bag --clock

If that doesn't work, you might need to look at the actual setup from which the data was recorded.

---

Originally posted by [Zack](https://answers.ros.org/users/949/zack/) with karma: 216 on 2011-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-08-16**:
i checked the tf tree, don't know why, but now there is no /narrow_stereo_optical_frame anymore, actually just 2 frames: /base_footprint and /odom_combined.  I had to use another similar bag file, it showed that /base_link wasn't the parent frame, changed it to /base_footprint, worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you record /tf in the bag? This is needed.
The fact the timestamps are inconsistent could indicate some node is broadcasting a new /tf at the moment of playing. Might wanna kill nodes broadcasting /tf and then play the bag file (which should have of course recorded /tf besides your data).

---

Originally posted by [Marco](https://answers.ros.org/users/920/marco/) with karma: 77 on 2011-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-08-16**:
i was using the bag files from grasp playpen dataset, which was well recorded and have /tf in it. And no other nodes was broadcasting /tf in my case